# How can I set the version number when uploading a file to SharePoint?

Tags: versioning

I have files from an old document control paradigm that I want to put into SharePoint.  If I have a file that the old paradigm called "version 14" how can I upload that document into SharePoint and assign it the initial version 14.0?  I was prompted for a version string when I uploaded and I provided one but when I view the file's version history, it starts at 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

What you've been prompted when uploading the file is probably a custom text column for that purpose. You should check that column.

Version history is differnet and built-in functionality and you don't get prompted for that but its initialy 0.1 and increases with every edit depending on library's versioning settings.

I don't know an easy way to jump to version 14.0 directly. For example one way would be to checkout-major checkin 14 times programatically.